# Can't login to phonegap build service- phone gap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Phone gap build service has some problem, when i trying to login it shows:

> There was an error with this action. Try again later.

even i can't create a new account with phone gap could service, i'am trying and trying, can anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same 2 me

fyi
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/hi_i_want_to_register_and_error_there_was_an_error_with_this_action_try_again_later

Hi All,

Seems this might have to do with our site.

We'll have a look and update you all once this has been resolved.

Sorry for the trouble this might have caused.